# Has anyone tried install PHP 8 in Windows Server 2012 IIS?

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-8, windows-server-2012, php-8

There is little or none of the tutorial or sharing on this topic. I'm wondering if IIS8 or 7.5 doesn't support PHP8 yet.

Don't mention installing it with WAMP or XAMMP. It's part of the project's requirements to have PHP with IIS only.

Comment: It is widely covered by media last year that Microsoft isn't supporting PHP 8 on Windows (but the PHP community can), https://betanews.com/2020/07/11/microsoft-drops-php-support/ So that's probably why no one talks about the topic any more. Please revisit your project's requirements, as they ask for a Microsoft supported platform for applications, PHP 8 on Windows isn't. You can choose to stay on PHP 7.x, or use PHP 8 on your own with community support (the steps do not change much).

Comment: There is no exact document indicating that it cannot be installed. I suggest you try it. If you have any questions, please come to discuss.

Comment: well. i guess i will need to be the "first mover" in this case.

Comment: @bravonet Has the problem been solved?